# Android ADB device is offline, unable to make it online

Tags: android, appium, appium-android, adb

command :  `adb devices`

after the running the command, I'm able to see that my device status is offline. How can I make it to online.

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   offline
```

I have set all the required Environment-Variables properly.

**In System Variable**

Variable Name : `%ANDROID_HOME%`

Variable Value : `C:\Users\apathan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

**Under Path Variable of System Variable**

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools

%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin

%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools

%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

The port might be occupied and make you unable to start the emulator. You can try:

1. `adb kill-server` to kill the service
2. Open the task manager and find all the adb processes and end them
3. Restart the virtual device, if you are using Android Studio, it's in AVD manager which locates in upper right corner
   [image]

Comment: No this is not working. Every time I need to create new Emulator because of the above-said issue.